# How to delete or move each image in directory of specific dimensions to new directory in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to find a way to do the following (Google is only returning results for finding):

1. Move all images of filetype (.jpg, .png, or .gif, etc.) of specified dimension(s) (such as 1920x1080, less than 1600 width, etc.) from current directory to another directory
2. Delete all images of specified dimension(s) in current directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will move all jpg, png, or gif files of dimension 1920x1080 from the current directory to `targetdir`:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for fname in *.jpg *.png *.gif
do
    read width height < <(exiv2 "$fname" 2>&1 | awk '/^Image size/{print $4,$6}')
    [ "$width" ] || continue
    [ "$width" -eq 1920 ] && [ "$height" -eq 1080 ] && mv "$fname" targetdir/
done
```

This looks through the current directory and deletes all jpg, png, or gif images of width less than 1600:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob
for fname in *.jpg *.png *.gif
do
    read width height < <(exiv2 "$fname" 2>&1 | awk '/^Image size/{print $4,$6}')
    [ "$width" ] || continue
    [ "$width" -lt 1600 ] && rm "$fname"
done
```

This uses the `exiv2` utility capture image size.  On a Debian-like system, `exiv2` can be installed by running `apt-get install exiv2`.  With minor modifications, similar utilities, such as ImageMagick's `identify`, could be used.

This script requires `bash`.

#### How it works

- `shopt -s nullglob`

  Ignore missing filetypes.
- `for fname in *.jpg *.png *.gif; do`

  This starts a loop over all files in the directory whose names end with `.jpg`, `.png`, and `.gif`.
- `read width height < <(exiv2 "$fname" 2>&1 | awk '/^Image size/{print $4,$6}')`

  This uses the `exiv2` utility to extract the image size.  Because `exiv2` produces several lines of output, `awk` is used to select the information that we need.
- `[ "$width" ] || continue`

  If we didn't recover an image size from the above command, then skip this file.  This will happen if, for example, the file was not really an image file.
- `[ "$width" -lt 1600 ] && rm "$fname"`

  If the image width meets our condition, then execute `rm` to delete the file.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the loop.

Comment: I followed your instructions, installed exiv2, saved the first script (move) as moveimg.sh in directory of the images and made it executable, and once I tried to run it, it returned the following error: `$ ./moveimg.sh 
./moveimg.sh: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token <'
./moveimg.sh: line 4:     read width height < <(exiv2 "$fname" 2>&1 | awk '/^Image size/{print $4,$6}')'`

Comment: @jin That means that the script is not running under bash.  The simplest solution is to run `bash ./moveimg.sh`.  Alternatively, if you want to be able to be able to execute it as `./moveimg.sh` with typing `bash` in front, then edit the file to add as the first line: `#!/bin/bash`.